Ошибка при запуске кода на pythonanywhere
Всем привет. Такая ошибка, что когда пытаюсь запустить бота в pythonanywhere(бесплатный хостинг), написанный на aiogram 2.25.2.
Я проверял, в консоле установлена версия aiogram 2.25.2, но при запуске выходит ошибка:
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]unreachable]

Но в PyCharm все работает нормально, как можно решить проблему?

Ну, не любят они ботов, сервер телеги там недоступен, насколько я понимаю.

Похоже, что дубликат появился даже в ленте похожих. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1549413
